# ASP.Net TextBox does not get refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a WebForm app(C#) and following code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "Working ...";
           
            int y = 0;
           
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
            {
                 y++;
            }           
            TextBox1.Text = "Ready!";            
        }
```

Probem is TextBox never shows "Working...".

I tried to put the textbox inside an update panel , still same behavior. This cannot be because of code running too fast, because the for loop adds 3-5 seconds of delay.

Is there anyway to make this work?

**Edit:**

I tried Albert D. Kallal's Answer, but his solution Still does not work for me!

So if both of use use the same code why it's not working for me.

To trim down the problem, I simplified code as below:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Run my code"            
           
   OnClientClick="$('#TextBox1').val('Please wait...')"  />
```

Textbox text does not get changed on click.

**Final Edit for the future readers:**
Albert D. Kallal's Answer is the complete solution. But it was not working for me. Reason:

My JQuery was getting blocked because I was using IIS Express.

This is the Console Error:

[image]

I used IIS Local and all ran good as expected!

Comment: I posted a edit2 in my post, and show a non jQuery example. And I also show without ClientIDModel="static".

Comment: Yes ,using https should work for you. (even when using IIS express). Note sure when visual studio changed, but it now by default uses + installs a copy of IIS express, and it should work just fine - assuming you use CDN via https and not http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in many ways, this "simple" question is a VERY good one.

Why? Because the answer involves a grasp and understanding of the web page life cycle. Without this simple grasp, then the code in question seems to have a strange or unexpected result.

Even MORE interesting? With the grasp of the page life cycle, I'll post some code that shows how do to this, and do it with GREAT ease, and not even require any special ajax or update panel code.

So, when you click your button, what occurs?

Well, the start of a post-back (or often called round trip) starts.

When you click the button, the web page is sitting on your desktop.

Then the web page is sent to the server side for processing.

You have this:

[image]

I must stress you do NOT have this:

[image]

so, the web server is waiting for ANY page to be posted to the server - and that page might not be YOUR page. Remember, unlike a desktop, there is ONE computer and ONE server here. The job of that server is to process incoming web pages - including all others. There is NOT a separate concept of memory, or variables or code or anything for EACH user. You have ONE web server.

OK, so now we click on that button, and the post-back (round trip, or so called page lifecycle starts).

this:

[image]

our web page is sent up to the server. You now have this:

[image]

On your desktop (client side browser), you see the spinner.

Now the server has the web page. Your code behind runs. I MUST stress that as your code behind makes updates to the web page, the end user browser does NOT see any changes.

So, your code could could wait 10 seconds, or 1 second. The web page is STILL up on the server.

Your code behind is thus free to modify that web page, but ONLY while it is up on the server side. And during that process, you the end user does NOT see ANY changes occurring (your browser copy still on your desktop!!).

What this really means is your code behind NEVER interacts directly with the user. Changes to the web page only occurs during that short time the web page is up on the server.

Then, and ONLY then, AFTER 100% of the code and processing server side is done, THEN and ONLY then does the page come back to the client side.

So, the page now travels back to client side.

[image]

Now, next part is VERY important:

On client side, the page is re-loaded. that includes blowing out all JavaScript code state and variables, re-starting the JavaScript, and re-display of the page.

Even MORE important? Server side your web page is nuked out of existence, disposed, and ALL of the page code and class variables go out of scope, and are TOSSED OUT! The web server is now read for any other post-back. Again: YOUR PAGE is NOT existing server side in memory any more - it is gone.

So, code behind changes to the browser are NEVER seen. You only get to see the one final page with ALL of the code changes made to the web page up on the server AFTER everything is done, and the one WHOLE page is re-sent back to the client!!!

Now, with the above concept in mind?

Then it becomes SUPER easy to have a button with a message, or spinner, or both that says "please wait...".

The trick of course is that asp.net buttons allow you to have two parts:

Part a: the post-back to the server (server side click event).

Part b: the client side button click (JavaScript).

So, let's drop in a button, have a 3 second fake delay, and have a please wait message display while we wait

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdLoadGrid" runat="server" Text="Load Data"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdLoadGrid_Click"
            OnClientClick="$('#myspin').show();"
            /> 
        <div id="myspin" style="display:none">
            Please wait ...
            <img src="../Content/wait2.gif" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
            runat="server" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            Width="42%" DataKeyNames="ID">
        </asp:GridView>
```

So, note how we just created/used a simple div, but "hidden".

And note how the button has both a client side click event, and a server side click event.

The above button is jQuery for client side.

So, code behind for the button click is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void cmdLoadGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
        // FAKE a 3 second delay
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL =
                @"SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description
                FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();    
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());   
                
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

Note VERY careful:

We do NOT have to worry about re-hide of the spinner and text.

Why? Well, because of the page life cycle. When the server side code is done, a WHOLE NEW web page is sent back to the client - and that re-plots, re-loads, and re-fresh our whole page - and as a result, our text + spinner text goes away automatic.

Note that I used a jQuery expression here.

eg:

```
    OnClientClick="$('#myspin').show();"
```

We could just use a pure JavaScript expression, so say this:

```
  OnClientClick="document.getElementById('myspin').style.display = 'inline';"
```

## Edit: Answer to posted question

So, in your case? Then your code would be this:

First, the markup (a button + text box, + client side code).

Again: I used jQuery here:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Run my code"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            OnClientClick="$('#TextBox1').val('Please wait...')"
            />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

        </asp:TextBox>
```

and your server side code: (it does not need the text box setting of please wait, since client side did this).

So, then this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
        {
            y++;
        }
        TextBox1.Text = "Ready!";
    }
```

And result is this:

[image]

## Edit2: A non jQuery example, and NOT using clientid=mode="static"

Note in posted working example, I had this:

[image]

So, for easy (shorter) expressions, I often use clientIDMode=static.

So, let's post a non jQuery example, and let's NOT use ClientIDModel="Static"

So, a working markup thus could be this: (no jQuery, and no clientidMode="static". The working markup then becomes this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Run my code"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            OnClientClick= "mywait();"
            />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" >

        </asp:TextBox>

        <script>
            function mywait() {
                document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value = 'Please Wait'

            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Excellent explanations and details.  All makes sense .

Comment: However when I copy your  code  in"Answer to posted question"  . For me I dont get intial value of please wait in Text Box. See my Updateed question.

Comment: Do you have jQuery installed and setup? That is a jQuery expression.  I can post a non jQuery expression if you wish. Note also the clientidMode=static setting

Comment: All good now see my latest update in question! Again Thanks for the "EXCELLENT" Answer!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do following.

1. When Button is pressed in browser
2. You want to show the word Working... in text box textbox1
3. You want to then do something on server as a long task
4. You want to return and change the text to Ready!

If the above is correct you can achieve this by doing following:

1. Give your textbox a clientID or unique class as well as ID (which is textbox1 in your case).
2. Add client side javascript to change the innerText or innerHTML of the element you can select by ID or class using DOM API.
3. When you have finished the operation the end code that changes it to Ready will keep working

The above is based on what you described as a problem.

If you can perform this operation on a handler then write than and return json from handler. This way you can use fetch to get to handler and perform operation without even doing postback on page. Simply control everything from front end and a nice single handler to perform operation instead of aspx.cs doing everything.

If you need to run this in background then look into something like hangfire or  signalR and perform the operation in background then notify the customer appropritely.

Comment: Geesh, that sure sounds like a VERY expensive way to code out this answer. See my answer below - you can do this with one line of js code, and you are done. In fact, you really don't even need one line of code, but just to add a js expression to the button click event.